# Axis 1.4 Soap Header add Username and Password

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, axis

I have an axis 1.4 web service client. i need to add username and password to soap message header. i did it, but i generates some undesirable attributes too.

This is my code :

```
   SOAPHeaderElement sec = new SOAPHeaderElement(
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
            "wsse:Security");

    SOAPHeaderElement token = new SOAPHeaderElement("",
            "wsse:UsernameToken");
    SOAPHeaderElement username = new SOAPHeaderElement("", "wsse:Username");
    SOAPHeaderElement password = new SOAPHeaderElement("", "wsse:Password");
    username.addTextNode("testuser");
    password.addTextNode("testpass");

    token.addChildElement(username);
    token.addChildElement(password);
    sec.addChildElement(token);
```

this is soap header that i want to generate:

```
    <soapenv:Header> 
<wsse:Security 
     xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">         
    <wsse:UsernameToken> 
        <wsse:Username>testuser</wsse:Username> 
        <wsse:Password>testpass</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken> 
</wsse:Security>
```

this is the header generated :

```
    <soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security 
    soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" 
    soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" 
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <wsse:UsernameToken 
        soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" 
        soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" 
        xmlns:wsse="">
            <wsse:Username 
                soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" 
                soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" 
                xmlns:wsse="">testuser</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password 
                soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" 
                soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" 
                xmlns:wsse="">testpass</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

other namespaces and attributes not problem but empty **xmlns:wsse=""** attributes cause my client to get error from web service. In soap-ui when i throw this empty attributes, i get successful response. In java code i get parsing error from web service.

I can't generate header without these attributes.If i add "wsse" prefix to header elements, it add **xmlns:wsse=""** attribute to these elements too.
Without wsse prefix i get error from web service.

How can i generate header with wsse prefix and without **xmlns:wsse=""** attribute in axis 1.4?

Comment: try `SOAPHeaderElement token = new SOAPHeaderElement(null, "wsse:UsernameToken");`

Comment: @Shloim - won't that cause an ambiguous method call error? That matches the signature of two constructors

Comment: So cast: `(String)null`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pass empty Strings in for the namespace URI, simply do the same thing you are doing for the Security tag:

```
String namespaceUri = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
SOAPHeaderElement sec = new SOAPHeaderElement(namespaceUri, "wsse:Security");
SOAPHeaderElement token = new SOAPHeaderElement(namespaceUri, "wsse:UsernameToken");
SOAPHeaderElement username = new SOAPHeaderElement(namespaceUri, "wsse:Username");
SOAPHeaderElement password = new SOAPHeaderElement(namespaceUri, "wsse:Password");
```